# Texturing whole item

Tags: texturing, uv

I want to texture my whole gun, not each part individually with smart UV project. How can I do this?

In edit mode, it's only possible to choose the selected object's mesh.

Comment: Do you mean join with `Ctrl`+`J`?

Comment: but in jont you cant animate it i meant texturing whole gun like cs vtf files

Comment: Make vertex groups when you join each object, and use `Ctrl`+`H` to hook them to an empty. You can then animate that

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean when you say "texture the whole gun". If you want to have all of the parts of the texture for the gun in the same mesh, you can do that, and map the various parts of the gun into the appropriate part of the texture image.

Comment: what do you mean by this do you mean all the texture in the same uv layer or what cause if thats what you mean  you understand it correctly

Comment: In my earlier comment, where I wrote, in part "...parts of the texture for the gun in the same _mesh_...", I meant to write "... parts of the texture for the gun in the same _image_...". Given what I actually wrote, I understand your confusion. It would be helpful to me to understand your question, and provide an answer, if you could post a screenshot of the gun, and post a copy of the texture images.